# Axios response get 200 code status, but sometimes data is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, axios, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using a Asp.net Core 2.2 Web API and ReactJS Axios, but sometimes (about 1 in 100 times) the response status is 200 but the data is an empty string.

The server side Controller code is:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SomeApiController : ControllerBase
{
                
    [HttpPost("GetData")]
    public IActionResult GetData([FromBody] int id_search)
    {
        // *Here I get a list data from back using the id_search*

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(List_data, Formatting.Indented));

        // *Here I write the json string in a text file, for debbug the data to send*

        return Ok(json);
    }
                
}
```

So far everything is fine, the json string i wrote in the text file have the data like this:

```
[
  {
    "cod_db": 1,
    "nom_db": "Nom1"
  },
  {
    "cod_db": 2,
    "nom_db": "Nom2"
  }
]
```

The Axios client javascript code is *(I'm using axios 0.19.2)*:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const clienteAxios = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://localhost:44364/api/'
}):

export default clienteAxios;
```

The client side axios method is:

```
const getData = () => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            // * The next headers I wrote because i think the problem could be CORS too, but I dont know if are necessary *
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true ,
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-type, Accept'
        }
    }

    var id_search = 1;
    clienteAxios.post('SomeApi/GetData', id_search, config)
        .then(d=>{
            console.log(d);
        })
        .catch(d=>{
            console.log("error");
            console.log(d);
        })
}
```

And most of the time the response have data, but sometimes *(it is difficult to happen)*, the response data is an empty string, even though the server side effectively sent data *(I know because the text file records the data to send)* and the .then method was execute with code status 200.

I don't know why this is happening, but I suspect that it could be because of CORS. I have this cors configurations in the Startup.cs archive:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            
    //CORS Activación 
    services.AddCors(
        options => options.AddPolicy("EnableCORS",
            builder =>
            {
                builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .Build();
            })
    );
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    //Enable CORS policy "AllowCors"
    app.UseCors("EnableCORS");

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong, or does anyone know why this is happening?

**Edit**: After a lot of attempts, I finally managed to recreate the error (remember that it is difficult to happen). The Chrome browser developer tools
Console tab shows nothing and the Network tab shows:

```
Headers:
    General:
        Request URL: https://localhost:44364/api/Login/GetDataBases
        Request Method: POST
        Status Code: 200 
        Remote Address: [::1]:44364
        Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
    Response Headers:
        access-control-allow-credentials: true
        access-control-allow-origin: *
        content-length: 0
        content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
        date: Fri, 04 Sep 2020 10:16:46 GMT
        server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
        status: 200
        vary: Origin
        x-powered-by: ASP.NET
    Request Headers:
        :authority: localhost:44364
        :method: POST
        :path: /api/Login/GetDataBases
        :scheme: https
        accept: application/json, text/plain, */ *
        accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
        accept-language: es-ES,es;q=0.9
        access-control-allow-credentials: true
        access-control-allow-headers: Content-type, Accept
        access-control-allow-origin: *
        cache-control: no-cache
        content-length: 1
        content-type: application/json
        origin: http://localhost:3000
        referer: http://localhost:3000/
        sec-fetch-dest: empty
        sec-fetch-mode: cors
        sec-fetch-site: cross-site
        user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36
    Request Payload:
        1
            No properties
Response:
    This request has no response data available.
```

Comment: your `List_data` is null

Comment: @arslan2012 Hi, List_data isn't null because i declare and set it before convert to json string (I specify this in the comment above)

Comment: so the problem must be when you set it

Comment: @arslan2012 It is not like that since the data to send is registered in the text file before the Ok return method, and this always have data

Comment: could you put the result of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(List_data, Formatting.Indented))` in the log file too?

Comment: Yes, this is what I put in the log file (I put the `json` string var that gets the result of the JsonConvert method)

Comment: what i'm worried is that when your app bugs out and `json` becomes an empty string, you wouldn't see it in your log file, because its an empty string....

Comment: but the json is never an empty string, not at least until the Ok return method, that's the problem ;-; I cant see when the json is convert to empty string

Comment: Access Control headers are useless in the request. They must be set server side in the response

Answer (score 0):

> I suspect that it could be because of CORS.

As you mentioned, the most of requests that ReactJS client send can get expected data, in my view, the issue would not be caused by CORS.

But configuring with both `AllowAnyOrigin` and `AllowCredentials` methods is insecure and not recommended, you can [specify the allowed origins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#set-the-allowed-origins) using `WithOrigins` method.

> sometimes (about 1 in 100 times) the response status is 200 but the data is an empty string.

Based on your code, it seems that you host the app on local, to troubleshoot the issue, you can set break point inside your action method, then debug and trace the `id_search` and `List_data`.

Besides, if you host your app on server, to troubleshoot the issue, you can try to [write application logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) then check application logs to find useful info.

```
private readonly ILogger _logger;
public SomeApiController(ILogger<SomeApiController> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

[HttpPost("GetData")]
public IActionResult GetData([FromBody] int id_search)
{

    _logger.LogInformation($"Client passed id_search is '{id_search}'");

    //var List_data = YourService.GetDataById(id_search);

    if (List_data.Count() < 1)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Can not get data based on id_search '{id_search}'");
    }

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(List_data, Formatting.Indented);

    _logger.LogInformation($"Get data based on id_search: {json}");
   

    return Ok(json);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, and yes, I set break point inside my action method, and `id_search` and `List_data` always are ok, even when the error occurs on the client side, so I don't know what else it could be

Comment: In browser developer tools Network tab, capture request and check actual response, is it empty?

Comment: yes, in network tab i get an empty string in data response :(